# Issues in generating JSON message in WSO2 EI

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to create a JSON message using the input xml message. My requirement is like this,

```
{

"ele1": > value from input xml tag1,

"ele2" > value from input xml tag2

......

}
```

- if the tag1 does not exists , either "ele1" should not send from the json message or "ele1" value equals to null.
- if tag1 value is equals to sample text, Json value should be like this. "ele1" : "sample text"

In this JSON message contains "@" in the Json Keys.

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sample" name="Sample" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <filter regex="sample text" source="//tag1/text()">
                <then>
                    <property name="ele1" scope="default" type="STRING" value="sample text"/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <property name="ele1" scope="default" type="STRING" value="null"/>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
                    "ele1": "$1",
                    "ele2": "$2"
                    }</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ele1"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//tag2/text()"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Request**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8290/sample' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data-raw '<root>
    <tag1>sample text</tag1>
    <tag2>some</tag2>
</root>'
```